# How to approach for tPacketCapture or MobiWol [Android] kind of app for packet

Tags: java, android, android-intent, vpn

I was trying to do application level packet filtering, So that I may stop some apps from using the internet [Wifi,3G etc]. I know it is technically feasible to do this as Mobiwol and tPacketCapture are doing it.

I tried figuring out what they are doing:

1. They are creating a VPNService..
2. They are writing and reading the logs - pCap file.

I need some guidance/suggestion in proceeding with the application level packet filtering because from VPNService, the traffic of the complete device will route through this service (VPNService) and from there I guess the mystery needs to be solved for which I need help?

Thanks